# How to draw vertical line on mschart that fills graph but isn't infinite?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I am trying to draw a vertical line that is anchored to a point. I tried to use the height of my Y axis which is fixed to draw the line, but it wasn't centered correctly. So right now I have an infinite line, but that I want is the line to just fill the graph like so

[image: http://i.imgur.com/OKdjcdU.png?1]

```
VerticalLineAnnotation lineannot = new VerticalLineAnnotation();
lineannot.AnchorDataPoint = chart.Series[item].Points.Last();
lineannot.LineColor = Color.Red;
lineannot.Width = 3;
lineannot.Visible = true;
lineannot.IsInfinitive = true;
chart.Annotations.Add(lineannot);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IsInfinitive` is complemented by `ClipToChartArea`; you can set the line to be clipped to a ChartArea like this:

```
lineannot.ClipToChartArea = chart.ChartAreas[item].Name;
```

assuming `item` is the right area name or index..
Note that `ClipToChartArea` takes the name of the chart area!

This is the simplest way to do it.

It is also possible to control an annotation's position and size directly:

```
// Note that directly after adding points this will return NaN:
double maxDataPoint = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum;
double minDataPoint = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum;

LineAnnotation annotation2 = new LineAnnotation();
annotation2.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
annotation2.AxisX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
annotation2.AxisY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
annotation2.AnchorY = minDataPoint;
annotation2.Height = maxDataPoint - minDataPoint;;
annotation2.Width = 0;
annotation2.LineWidth = 2;
annotation2.StartCap = LineAnchorCapStyle.None;
annotation2.EndCap = LineAnchorCapStyle.None;
annotation2.AnchorX = 21;  // <- your point
annotation2.LineColor = Color.Pink; // <- your color
chart1.Annotations.Add(annotation2);
```